# Turning off "Remember playback position"

Tags: music.app

Version: I have no software updates pending on MacBook Pro, iPhone, or iPad.

Yesterday, I saw a setting on some device for "Remember playback position" and turned it on.

Today on the MacBook Pro, I find that I do not like the new behavior.  Any track that I have sampled (listened for a few seconds), if I click on it again after hearing/doing other things, it starts where the sample ended instead of the beginning.

So I went through all four pages of the Music settings and that option does not appear.  Didn't find it in System settings, either.  So, I thought, maybe they copied it from another device during Sync.  Looked on the iPhone, and there is no such setting!

**Where is it, so I can turn it off?!?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get Info

Go to your Music Library and select every song there (by pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>). Then, right click on them and select "**Get Info**".

In the Options tab of the Get Info panel, there should be a checkbox for "Remember playback position", uncheck it and click "OK" to confirm your choice.

[image: Screenshot of the Options tab in Get Info in the Music app (take from https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/make-apple-music-remember-play-back-position.2387952/)]

Comment: Wow, that's strange.  The Info pane showed it as “-” meaning it was on for some and off for others.  But it was happening on tracks that I did not touch yesterday!

Comment: @WGroleau Maybe there's a generalized setting somewhere. I'll see if I can find it (and come back to you if I do). ;)

Comment: In https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1840318 (fifteen years old) and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2394763 /8thirteen years), it's in the info pane separate for each track.  So, … weird.

Comment: @WGroleau Yeah, that's probably an unknown feature that very few people know about, so IMO, Apple doesn't really care if it's buggy or not really clear where the settings are or how to use them.